# alter table add contraint (postgresql)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

Below I have a string I am attempting to execute in postgres, but I am receiving an SQL state error (42601) which I understand to be a syntax issue.
I have checked through the documentation on executing this statement and feel as though I have it correct. Any syntactical suggestions in order to correct this statement would be greatly appreviated.

```
ALTER TABLE ASeriesResults ADD  CONSTRAINT DF_ASeriesResults_CaseId  
DEFAULT ((0)) FOR CaseId;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you adding a constraint if you want a default value?

A default value is not a constraint (and I don't think anything [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html) suggests that you need `add constraint` to add a default value):

```
ALTER TABLE ASeriesResults ALTER COLUMN CaseId SET DEFAULT 0;
```